# Form with ListBox is submitted empty when submitted onchange

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Working on ASP.NET MVC with Razor, the problem is straightforward: I have a form with a select element which I submit via Javascript when the selection changes. But the form is always empty on submission. The selected value is not enclosed, the FormCollection always empty.
There's probably some silly mistake I'm making somewhere, but I've wasted 2 hours already on getting this to work, so a different perspective might help.

The code in the cshtml view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SetFilter", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "filter"}))
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("tags", new SelectList(Model.Filters, "value", "text"), htmlAttributes: new { @id = "topnav_filters", onchange = "submitFilter()" });
    }
```

The function doing the submitting:

```
function submitFilter()
{
    var debug = $("#filter");
    $("#filter").submit();
}
```

And the controller action supposed to get the data (doesn't do anything yet, currently only serves to set a breakpoint and check if I'm finally getting anything):

```
    public ActionResult SetFilter(FormCollection form)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: does it hit the method `public ActionResult SetFilter(FormCollection form)` if  you place` break point` there??

Comment: If thats the only control in the form, then the parameter should be `string tags` (or `int`?) not `FormCollection form`

Comment: @ozil: Yes, it hits the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

StephenMucke brought it up above, but that was only part of the problem. The controller action did in fact look like this at first:

```
 public ActionResult SetFilter(string tag)
{
    return View();
}
```

but tag was always null, so I tried other things. However, you will notice that the variable name is "tag", not "tags". Changing it to "tags" did indeed fix the problem.

I am somewhat dumbfounded by this. I never would have expected the binder to attempt to match the name of an input element to the actual name of a variable (a thing that I until now always considered completely meaningless as soon as a program ran through the compiler). I supposed it would just go by order or maybe try to discern datatype or somesuch. I also understand the mapping of property names to input elements in the Bind[] command. But I'd really never have expected the thing to match variable names...

Comment: Probably worth doing some research and read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) - this is the most basic fundamental principal of model binding :)